# How can I theme webform?

Tags: 6, theming, webforms

I've got a website with a custom theme who was developed by an external group. I would like to custom the webform appearance.

In my form, there are grid fields. And these grid fields need to have a description. But in my custom theme, the description appears under the grid and I would like it appears just between the label and the grid. I hope you see what I mean.

In the `theming.txt` it seems that I have to edit the `webform-form.tpl.php` and save it to my theme folder. But in this file, there are only PHP code. So, how can I modify the HTML structure?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Editing the template.php file of my custom theme and more specifically the theme_form_element() function. In that function, simply move these 3 lines where I want :

```
if (!empty($element['#description'])) {
    $output .= ' <div class="description">' . $element['#description'] . "</div>\n";
}
```